# Text doesn't fit into borders - CSS

Tags: css

Here is my working example [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/u7hzqwt2/). The Problem is that if the text is long it goes out of the border and I want somehow to prevent this. any suggestions?

```css
.order-page-left {
  width: 275px;
  background: white;
}
.orders-list .item {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  color: #181818;
  outline: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.orders-list .item .inner {
  padding: 7px 0 10px;
}
.orders-list .item .inner:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, white 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(100%, white));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, white 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, white 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, white 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, white 100%);
}
.orders-list .item .detail {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
  width: 50px;
}
.orders-list .item .detail .smaller {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #808080;
}
.orders-list .item .name {
  margin-left: 65px;
}
.orders-list .item .name .info {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<div class="order-page-left">
  <div class="orders-list">
    <a id="documentLink0" href="/service/sales/documents/order/quickView.do?envId=406519&amp;isDraft=false&amp;isNewDoc=true&amp;docStatus=" class="item highligh">


      <!-- onClick="getDocumentDetails(this, event);" -->
      <div class="inner cfx">
        <div class="detail">

          <b>
       
                               <span class="showDate">
                                    <span class="date" style="display: none;">03.07
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="exp_date">
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="docDate" style="display: inline;">11.05
                                    </span>
                               </span>
       
        </b>

          <div class="smaller">
            <span class="showDate">
                                    <span class="date" style="display: none;">11:25
                                    </span>
            <span class="exp_date">
                                    </span>
            <span class="docDate" style="display: inline;">09:07
                                    </span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="name">
          <b>AUTO EDIBUYER1</b>



          <div class="info">
            142.81 JMETER_20150703112433000000120:1:L
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to resize borders based on how long is the text?

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

try using `overflow:hidden;` to prevent overflowing text out of element

```css
.order-page-left {
 width: 275px;
 background: white;
}
.orders-list .item {
 display: block;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
 color: #181818;
 outline: 0;
 position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.orders-list .item .inner {
 padding: 7px 0 10px;
}

.orders-list .item .inner:before {
 content: "";
 height: 100%;
 width: 30px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 1;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, white
  100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,
  255, 255, 0)), color-stop(100%, white));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
  white 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, white
  100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, white
  100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, white
  100%);
}

.orders-list .item .detail {
 float: left;
 padding: 0 0 0 15px;
 width: 50px;
}

.orders-list .item .detail .smaller {
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #808080;
}

.orders-list .item .name {
 margin-left: 65px;
}


.orders-list .item .name .info {
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<div class="order-page-left">
    <div class="orders-list">
        <a id="documentLink0" href="/service/sales/documents/order/quickView.do?envId=406519&amp;isDraft=false&amp;isNewDoc=true&amp;docStatus=" class="item highligh">
     
    
        <!-- onClick="getDocumentDetails(this, event);" -->
     <div class="inner cfx">
      <div class="detail">
       
        <b>
       
                               <span class="showDate">
                                    <span class="date" style="display: none;">03.07
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="exp_date">
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="docDate" style="display: inline;">11.05
                                    </span>
                               </span>
       
        </b>
       
       <div class="smaller">
                                <span class="showDate">
                                    <span class="date" style="display: none;">11:25
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="exp_date">
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="docDate" style="display: inline;">09:07
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="name">
       <b>AUTO EDIBUYER1</b>
       
       
       
       <div class="info">
        142.81 JMETER_2015070311243300dddddddddddd0000120:1:L
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but can you make it a bit shorter? So that it wouldn't be so close to the end on the right

Answer (score 0):

Use `word-wrap: break-word;` on the holding container. Check out the [updated fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/u7hzqwt2/1/)

Comment: Can you make so that instead of word wrap the div size changed?

Comment: Yeah, don't give the holding container a fixed size and change it to `display: inline-block` instead of `display: block`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `word-wrap: break-word` to shift the extended text that to new line.

```css
.order-page-left {
  width: 275px;
  background: white;
}
.orders-list .item {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  color: #181818;
  outline: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.orders-list .item .inner {
  padding: 7px 0 10px;
}
.orders-list .item .inner:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, white 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(100%, white));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, white 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, white 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, white 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, white 100%);
}
.orders-list .item .detail {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
  width: 50px;
}
.orders-list .item .detail .smaller {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #808080;
}
.orders-list .item .name {
  margin-left: 65px;
}
.orders-list .item .name .info {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #808080;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="order-page-left">
  <div class="orders-list">
    <a id="documentLink0" href="/service/sales/documents/order/quickView.do?envId=406519&amp;isDraft=false&amp;isNewDoc=true&amp;docStatus=" class="item highligh">


      <!-- onClick="getDocumentDetails(this, event);" -->
      <div class="inner cfx">
        <div class="detail">

          <b>
       
                               <span class="showDate">
                                    <span class="date" style="display: none;">03.07
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="exp_date">
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="docDate" style="display: inline;">11.05
                                    </span>
                               </span>
       
        </b>

          <div class="smaller">
            <span class="showDate">
                                    <span class="date" style="display: none;">11:25
                                    </span>
            <span class="exp_date">
                                    </span>
            <span class="docDate" style="display: inline;">09:07
                                    </span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="name">
          <b>AUTO EDIBUYER1</b>



          <div class="info">
            142.81 JMETER_20150703112433000000120:1:LExtended
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding `display:table;` for `.order-page-left`

```
.order-page-left {
  display: table;
  width: 275px;
  background: white;
}
```